# Trying to access an external API with http-proxy-middleware in a React.js App

Tags: reactjs, http

I'm trying to access an external API using http-proxy-middleware.

This is my setupProxy.js file:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    "/api/palettes/random?format=json",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://www.colourlovers.com",
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false
    })
  );
};
```

Here is my axios request:

```
const res = await axios.get("/api/palettes/random?format=json");
```

When I run it locally, the url runs http://localhost:3000/api/palettes/random?format=json, seemingly ignoring the middleware.

Again, when I host the files in AWS, the GET request runs https://master.d35k32uc23ao8f.amplifyapp.com/api/palettes/random/, ignoring the middleware.

Not sure quite where I'm going wrong here, you can check out the repo if it's of use: https://github.com/ZachPinfold/swatchedio_v02

The axios request can be found in: `src/colors`, the setupProxy is in `src/setupProxy`

I would simply add the proxy into my root .json, but it's giving me problems during deployment.

Appreciate any help in advance.